# Why does my first test pass but the rest fail?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have the following tests written for an AngularJS service. When I run them all at once, the first test, `'should exist'`, passes, but the rest fail with the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProcessorProvider <- aProcessor
```

My tests:

```
describe('MyService', () => {
    let a: any, b: any, c: any;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule'));

    beforeEach(inject( (_a_, _b_) => {
        a = _a_;
        b = _b_;
        c = b.getProperty('foo');
    }));

    afterEach( () => {
        a = null;
        b = null;
        c = null;
    });

    //passes
    it('should exist', () => {
        expect(a).toBeDefined();
        expect(b).toBeDefined();
        expect(c).toBeDefined();
    });

    //all fail
    describe('when something happens', () => {
        it('should be a frog', () => {
            let isFrog: boolean = a.isFrog();
            expect(isFrog).toBeTruthy();
        });

        it('should not be a moose', () => {
            let isMoose: boolean = b.isMoose();
            expect(isMoose).toBeFalsy();
        });

        it('should have no soul', () => {
            let soul: any = c.getSoul();
            expect(soul).toBeNull();
        });
    });

});
```

When I run these test individually, they pass, but when I run them all at once, the last three fail. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the call to `angular.mock.module()` in a function so it runs before every test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('myModule');
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result with this approach, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of how the `a` and `b` services are implemented? Are they configured as singletons for example?